# Actualizar datos SQL desde tabla html

Tags: javascript, sql-server, php7, html-tabla

Tengo la siguiente tabla:

```
<table role="grid">
    <thead>
        <th>Orden</th>
        <th>Fecha Fab.</th>
        <th>Norden</th>
        <th>Color</th>
        <th>Cliente</th>
        <th>Metros</th>
        <th>Tiempo</th>
        <th>Fecha Ent.</th>
        <th>Operario</th>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <?php
        //Obtenemos los datos la máquina 41
        $sql = "
            SELECT DISTINCT  Orden, FFab, Norden, Color, Client, Metros, Tiempo, FEnt,Operario
            FROM (
                (
                    Ordenes 
                        INNER JOIN VCLIENTE ON VCLIENTE.Clie_codigo = Ordenes.OF_Cod_Cli
                ) 
                INNER JOIN ARTITTEC ON ARTITTEC.Tec_codigo = Ordenes.OF_Cod_Art
            ) 
            INNER JOIN VTiempos ON  VTiempos.Of_n_orden= Ordenes.OF_N_Orden 
                AND Vtiempos.OF_LIN =Ordenes.OF_Lin
            ORDER BY Orden asc, Fecha asc";

            $stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $sql );
            if( $stmt === false) {
                die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true) );
            }

            while($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)){
            ?>
                <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $row['Orden'];?></td>
                <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $row['FFab'];?></td>
                <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $row['Norden'];?></td>
                <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $row['Color'];?></td>
                <td role="gridcell" ><?php echo $row['Client']; ?></td>
                <td role="gridcell" ><?php echo $row['Metros']; ?></td>
                <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $row['Tiempo'];?></td>
                <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $row['FEnt'];?></td>
                <td role="gridcell"><?php echo $row['Operario'];?></td>
            </tr>
            </b>
            </font> 
        <?php { ?>
    </tbody>
</table>

<div class="k-pager-wrap k-grid-pager k-widget k-floatwrap" data-role="pager">
    <span class="k-pager-info k-label"></span>
</div>
```

Me gustaría poder actualizar el dato ***Orden*** desde la tabla html en el registro SQL.

El `$row` va a sacar varios registros. El campo **Orden**, esta relacionado al Norden (que es el número de pedido)

¿Como podría hacerlo?  Estoy bastante pez en este tema, si podéis poner un código de ejemplo lo agradecería.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Ya he actualizado la pregunta con tu edición. ¿Podrías ayudarme a resolverla? Gracias

Comment: Cual es el problema que obtiene lo que has realizado, se muestra algún error?

Comment: La tabla es la siguiente: https://ibb.co/mR5zm3T         Quiero desde esa misma tabla poder editar el primer campo, que va ligado al número de orden y actualizarlo en la base de datos sql